# PyCharm editor stops responding to keyboard (2017.2.1 Professional for Mac )

Tags: python, pycharm, macos-sierra, jetbrains-ide

My IDE periodically stops responding to keyboard inputs entirely (still responds to the mouse perfectly), and I have to quit and reopen PyCharm to fix it.

Googling reveals that the same bug was common in Ubuntu systems about a year ago, and the solution was to kill iBus, but my version of PyCharm has no mention of iBus in its settings, and I'm not sure that macs use iBus at all.

Any ideas? This is PyCharm Professional 2017.2.1 on macOS Sierra 10.12.16.